# How find this limit $I=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^a\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin{(nx)}\cos^n{x}dx\right)=b$

Tags: integration, limits

If the constant $a,b\neq 0$ such 
$$
I=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[%
n^{a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\left(nx\right)\cos^{n}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x
\right] = b
$$

find $a,b$

My idea: since
$$\sin{(nx)}=\dfrac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}$$
$$\cos{x}=\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$$
so
$$(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}e^{i(n-k)x}e^{-ikx}$$
so
$$\sin{(nx)}\cos^n{x}=\dfrac{1}{2i}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2^n}(e^{inx}-e^{-inx})(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n=\dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}\cdot i}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\binom{n}{k}(e^{i(2n-2k)x}-e^{-2ikx}\right)$$
then I can't.Thank you

Comment: Sorry but (as mentioned before) these are not "ideas".

Comment: Have you studied the general formula for : $$\int \sin^n(x) cos^m (x) dx $$

Comment: To follow up on the previous hint, it should be possible to write $\sin(nx)$ as a combination of products of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ (i.e. to make all the coefficients 1). DeMoivre's formula and the binomial theorem should make this straightforward: $\sin(nx) = \text{Im} ( \exp(inx) ) = \text{Im} \left ( \exp(ix) \right )^n = \text{Im} \left ( \left ( \cos(x) + i \sin(x) \right )^n \right )$.

Comment: An idea inspired by Wolfram Alpha: the antiderivative appears to be a sum of cosines of frequency $2,4,\dots,2n$. Perhaps one could take this as an ansatz, differentiate both sides, and find the coefficients.

Comment: Eh, changed to $n^2$ ? $n$ was better.

Comment: @gar,I don't know $n$ is better.or $n^2$

Comment: Okay, I was kidding. I see it's $n^a$ now!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an approach with very basic steps
$$
\begin{align}
&n\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(nx)\cos^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{n}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(nx)\cos((n-2k)x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac12\left[\vphantom{\frac12}\sin(2(n-k)x)+\sin(2kx)\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2kx)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac1{2k}(1-\cos(k\pi))\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1^k-(-1)^k}{k}\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\int_0^2\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{7}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\int_0^2\sum_{k=1}^nx^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{8}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}{k}\tag{9}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{n+1-k}}{n+1-k}\tag{10}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{-k}}{1-(k-1)/n}\tag{11}\\
&\to\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\tag{12}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\ \:(1):$ $\cos^n(x)=\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^n=\frac1{2^n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{i(n-2k)x}=\frac1{2^n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cos((n-2k)x)$
$\ \:(2):$ $\sin(A)\cos(B)=\frac12\left[\vphantom{\frac12}\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)\right]$
$\ \:(3):$ combine identical terms
$\ \:(4):$ integrate
$\ \:(5):$ evaluate
$\ \:(6):$ expand and integrate to get $(5)$
$\ \:(7):$ substitute $x\mapsto x-1$
$\ \:(8):$ expand quotient
$\ \:(9):$ integrate
$(10):$ reindex $k\mapsto n+1-k$
$(11):$ distribute over sum
$(12):$ dominated convergence: dominated by $k2^{-k}$
$(13):$ geometric sum

---

**Proof and Use of a Nice Recursion**

Using a trigonometric identity and integrating by parts, we see that
$$
\begin{align}
I_n
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(nx)\cos^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[\vphantom{\frac12}\sin((n+1)x)\cos(x)-\cos((n+1)x)\sin(x)\right]\cos^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin((n+1)x)\cos^{n+1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos((n+1)x)\frac{\mathrm{d}\cos^{n+1}(x)}{n+1}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin((n+1)x)\cos^{n+1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac1{n+1}+\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin((n+1)x)\cos^{n+1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2I_{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
Substituting $n\mapsto n-1$ and solving for $I_n$ yields the recursion mentioned by gar and Chris's sis:
$$
I_n=\frac12\left(I_{n-1}+\frac1n\right)
$$
Multiplying by $2^n$ gives
$$
2^nI_n=2^{n-1}I_{n-1}+\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}
$$
and since $I_0=0$, we get
$$
2^nI_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k-1}}{k}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
n\,I_n
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k-n-1}}{k}\\
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{-k}}{n+1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{-k}}{1-(k-1)/n}\\
\end{align}
$$
which is $(11)$ above.

Comment: The big problem is that the integral involves a harmonic number and a hypergeometric function. I reduced the integration to the $\left(0,1\right)$ interval but it was not helpful. In addition, the integrand has some nice feature at ${\pi/2 \over n  + 1}$. Good luck. You did a nice job.

Comment: @FelixMarin: does this concern this answer, or another?

Comment: It was just a general comment about my attempt to find the limit. I still struggle with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

*May I give it a try in one line?* Since $\displaystyle I_k=\frac{I_{k-1}}{2}+\frac{1}{2k}\Rightarrow 2^kI_k=2^{k-1}I_{k-1}+\frac{2^{k-1}}{k}$, then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(nx)\cos^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}{k}=1$$
as a consequence of the **Cesaro-Stolz theorem**.

Comment: Clarifying a little bit: taking $a_k = 2^k I_k$ and $b_k = 2^k$, we get from the Cesaro Stolz theorem that $\lim_{k \to \infty} I_k = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_k/b_k = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k - a_{k-1}}{b_k - b_{k-1}} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{2^{k-1}}{k 2^{k-1}} = \lim_{k \to \infty} 1/k$. Multiplying through by $k$ gives the desired result. Nice proof.

Comment: @Ian if you apply it correctly, you get the correct answer. $\displaystyle a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}{k}$ and $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n}$

Comment: @Ian Thanks :-)

Comment: I like my way because you do not have to solve the recurrence. :)

Comment: We miss you on chat :-( I hope your work is going well.

Answer (score 5):

Let

\begin{align*}
  I_n &= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin{(nx)}\cos^n{x}dx
\end{align*}

A reduction formula seems to be
\begin{align*}
  I_n &= \frac{1}{2}\left(I_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
  I_0 &= 0
\end{align*}

Simplifying that gives:

\begin{align*}
  I_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k\left(n-k+1\right)}
\end{align*}

and the generating function for $I_n$ is 
\begin{align*}
  G(z) &= -\frac{\log{\left(1-z\right)}}{\left(2-z\right)}
\end{align*}

Now, we need to get the asymptotics for $[z^n]$

**Update**

For the asymptotic analysis, we may use the theorem VI.12, pp.434 in [analytic combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf), which states:

> Let $a(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n$ and $b(z) = \sum_n b_n z^n$ be two power series with radii of convergence $\alpha > \beta \ge 0$, respectively. Assume that
>   $b(z)$ satisfies the ratio test,$$\frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n}\to \beta \; \; \text{ as } n\to\infty$$
>
> Then, the coefficients of the product $f(z) = a(z)\cdot b(z)$ satisfy $$[z^n] f(z) \sim a\left(\beta\right)b_n\; \; \text{ as } n\to\infty$$ provided $a(\beta) \ne 0$

Hence, in our gf, let

\begin{align*}
  a(z) &= \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}z^n \\
  b(z) &= \sum_n \frac{1}{n} z^n \\
  \implies [z^n]G(z) &\sim \frac{1}{2}\cdot a(1)\cdot \frac{1}{n} \;\;\text{since $\frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n}\to 1$} \\
  [z^n]G(z) &\sim \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\to\infty} n \cdot I_n &= 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Your formula for $I_n$ is the same as $(11)$ in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/843742). That's worth +1 :-)

Comment: Hi @robjohn , thanks! I have now completed my answer after much going through the texts.

Answer (score 4):

Continuing with what gar did, if you do partial fractions on the sum for $I_n$, you get

$$\frac{1}{2^k (n-k+1)} = \frac{2^{-n-1}}{n-k+1} + \frac{1-2^{-1-n}}{(n+1) 2^{k}}.$$

The sum over the second term is $O(1/n)$, and this estimate is sharp. The sum over the first term is $O(n 2^{-n})$, which you can obtain by replacing $k$ with $n$ (which can only increase the term). So the first term will drop out as $n \to \infty$ no matter what $a$ is, and all we need be concerned with is the second term. Moreover for $a<1$ it will converge to zero, for $a>1$ it will diverge. For $a=1$ we should have a finite limit, which is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \left (1-2^{-1-n} \right )}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} = 1$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{n}{2^k(n-k+1)}\le\frac{k}{2^k}$ when $k\le n$. This allows the use of dominated convergence.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've done already, notice that since the LHS is real, the RHS is equal to its own real part. Because of the $1/i$, this means we need to compute the imaginary part of the sum. We get (for the sum):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \left (  \sin((2n-2k)x) - \sin(-2kx) \right )$$

This should be easy to integrate term by term, and because you're on $[0,\pi/2]$ and all the frequencies are even, all the definite integrals should have a very simple form.

You also should do your binomial expansion again, because I'm fairly sure there is a small error. You should have frequency $n+k-(n-k)=2k$ with a plus sign and frequency $-n+k-(n-k)=-2n+2k$ with a minus sign.